# Why CSV data rows are coming through as individual text files and not in body

Tags: python, dataframe, smtp

I am trying to get the data from a CSV file and send that in an email using mimecast. Currently I am getting the headers from the file into the body but cant get the rows to come through. For some reason they are being placed in text files individually. Here is my stuff:

```py
lines_to_send = []
with open(file, mode='r') as file:
    # reading the CSV file
    csvFile = csv.reader(file)

    # displaying the contents of the CSV file
    for line in csvFile:
        lines_to_send.append(line)
```

This is what I use to get the rows from the CSV file

```py
usernameEmail = '...'
passwordEmail = '...'
toEmails = ['...']

def send_mail(toaddrs_list, msg_lines, fromaddr, subject="Title"):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('...')
    s.starttls()
    s.set_debuglevel(1)
    s.login(usernameEmail, passwordEmail)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    sender = fromaddr
    recipients = toaddrs_list
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    if fromaddr is not None:
        msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)
    
    for mime_text in build_message(msg_lines):
        msg.attach(mime_text)

    s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())

def build_message(lines):
    return [MIMEText('[\'' + '\', \''.join(line) + '\']\n') for line in lines]

send_mail(toEmails, lines_to_send, usernameEmail)
```

This is what I have to send the email. I have also included a photo of the email that I have currently.

Email Screenshot
[image: Email Screenshot]

I have tried a lot. Any thoughts?

Comment: `build_message()` turns each row into a separate string. Then you attach each of these as a separate attachment with `msg.attach(mime_text)`.

Comment: @Barmar I see what you are saying. Do you have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: If you want all the CSV lines as a single attachment, don't call `msg.attach()` in a loop.

Comment: @Barmar I see. This still however packs all the rows together and now it sends all in one file. I want to be able to see it in the body

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't matter whether each row is in its own file or not. I want to be able to see that data in the body of the email and not in the txt files

Comment: Then don't use `msg.attach()` at all, just put it in the message text. `msg.attach()` is for creating attachments.